# How to maintain selected value in dropdownlist with specific conditions

Tags: asp.net

Hi I have two dropdownlists in master page

ddlCountry and ddlState I am binding both dropdowns using SQLDatasource. I have used SelectParameters in ddlState to bind it according to selected country. Sample:

```
<SelectParameters>
  <asp:SessionParameter SessionField="CountryName" Name="CountryName"><asp:SessionParameter>
</SelectParameters>
```

Flow: When I select value from ddlCountry it is redirecting user to another page and binding ddlState(This is working fine)

Problem: ddlCountry is resseting to its initial state after the process. I need to maintain the selected item of ddlCountry after user is redirected to other page.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`When I select value from ddlCountry it is redirecting user to another page and binding ddlState`

if you have written `dropdown_indexchange` event the pass the selected value in the url.
And on the page load of other page set the selected index(after filling the dropdown list).

Comment: My Dropdown is in Master page and I have tried 

DropDownList ddlCountry =(DropDownList) Master.FindControl("ddlCountry");

in my second page but ddlCountry shows null records.